# Time() Function in PHP always shows same value

Tags: php, loops, time

If I use time() in a loop, I always get the same values for time. But time should be a function and not a variable, so I dont understand what the problem is.

```
<?php

$i= 0;

while($i < 1000)
{
?>
 <br>
<?php
echo time();
$i= $i +1;
}
```

?>

Comment: This will execute in under a second. If you are looking for more exact measurements of performance try `microtime()`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) for `time()`, it

> Returns the current time measured in the number of **seconds** since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Emphasis mine. `while ($i < 1000)` will likely execute in under a second, so all of the timestamps are quite likely to be the same for any given run of the program (but should be different on the next run).

Comment: Yay! You hit 10k!

Comment: Woop woop woop!

Comment: ahyes you are right, I thought it were in milliseconds because I used also uniqid() before and that function is using milliseconds. Thanks and gratulations :D